# Write Python strings to file for reading by a Perl script

Tags: python, string, perl

I'd like to write results to a txt file in Python, where each line needs to be in the format sentence-tab-score:

`<s> This is the sentence </s>  42`

The intent is to have a "score_results" Perl script read the sentences and scores, where each line is parsed w/ `@fields = split(/\t/)`:

```
$count = 0;
$best = "";
$bestlp = -1000000;

while (<>) {
        s/\s+[\r\n]+$//o;
        @fields = split(/\t/);
        if ($fields[1] > $bestlp) {
                $bestlp = $fields[1];
                $best = $fields[0];
        }

        if ((++$count % 5) == 0) {
                print "$best\n";
                $bestlp = -1000000;
        }
}
```

My issue is writing the results sentences in Python, with

```
with open("results.txt", "wb") as fout:
    for sentence, score in zip(resultsSentences, resultsScores):
        fout.write(sentence + "\t" + str(score) + "\n")
```

doesn't work because the tabs in the Python-written file end up as new lines, and thus not recognized in the Perl script as a tab. The first few lines of "results.txt" look like

```
<s> I have seen it on him , and could write to it </s> 
    42.0
<s> I have seen it on him , and could migrate to it </s> 
    42.0
<s> I have seen it on him , and could climb to it </s> 
    42.0
```

But the example results that run with the Perl script look like

```
<s> I have seen it on him , and could write to it </s>  -46.8152390767177
<s> I have seen it on him , and could migrate to it </s>    -50.5058224637686
<s> I have seen it on him , and could climb to it </s>  -48.5949070950928
```

And then the "score_results" Perl script runs with the bash call
`cat results.txt | ./score_results.pl > scores.temp`

Given I'd prefer to use the provided Perl script, how can I modify the script and/or write my results sentences differently?

Comment: "the Python tab is not recognized in Perl as a tab" - a tab is tab (ASCII 0x09), period. Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Okay thanks @isedev, please see the add'l file-writing info above.

Comment: Since the problem is outside the provided code and the OP is less than eager to construct a [mcve], voting to close as unclear.

Comment: @alavin89 Do you have an example of a text file that is successfully parsed by the perl script? In that case, your problem could be solved by comparing that input file with the file created by your python script above in a hex editor. Read a single line, byte by byte, side by side, or use diff, to see where they differ

Comment: So, with your edit, did you answer your question? If not, can you print out a bit of your resultsSentences and resultsScores?  Do resultsSentences end with \n?

Comment: The issue was that there was already a `\n` in the `sentence`. So this was resolved with `fout.write(sentence[:-2] + "\t" + str(score) + "\n")`